# Linked List in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I am having some trouble running this linked list implementation (containing words as data). Problem is when I try to print the words (that I inserted) in the Linked List,I get nothing. What am I doing wrong, breaking my head over this? I hope it's not something silly. Anyway here's the code -

```
typedef struct node
{
    void *data;
    struct node *next;
} NODE;

NODE *new_node(void *data)
{
    NODE *new = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    if(new)
    {
        new->data = data;
        new->next = NULL;
        return new;
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}

void print_list(NODE *head, void (print_fn) (void*))
{
    if(head && head->next)
    {
        while(head->next)
        {
            if(print_fn)
                print_fn(head->data);
            else
                printf("Word: %s\n", (char *)head->data);
            head = head->next;
        }
    }
    return;
}

void append(NODE **head, NODE *node)                                                                                  
{
    NODE *tmp = *head;
    if(tmp && node)
    {
        while(tmp->next)
            tmp = tmp->next; 
        (*head)->next = node; /*add as last node*/
    }
    return;
}


NODE *create_list()
{
    FILE *dict_file = fopen("trial.txt", "r");

    if(dict_file)
    {
        NODE *head = new_node(NULL);
        if(!head) return NULL;

        char word[20];
        int first  = TRUE;
        memset(word, '\0', 20);

        while(fgets(word, sizeof(word), dict_file) != NULL )
        {
            if(first)
            {
                head->data = (void*)word;
                first = FALSE;
            }
            else
            {
                append(&head, new_node((void*)word));
            }
        }
        fclose(dict_file);
        return head;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ERROR: File not found");
        return NULL;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NODE *head = create_list();

    if(!head)
    {
        printf("ERROR: Either malloc() failed or data not found\n");
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        print_list(head, NULL);
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: As a general comment, you should really avoid using the word new as a variable name.

Comment: You forgot to provide the code for "print_list" function.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This has become quite a long answer. Don't take this personally, but you have made quite a few rookie mistakes. I have met with many people at university whom I helped to learn the C language and programming in general, so I've got used to notice these kinds of things.

### The important issues I could find

- **You assign a pointer to a stack variable to `words`**
  This is completely bad, because that value will be overwritten once the execution gets out of the function that creates it. *Solution: copy the content of that variable into a heap variable.*
- **Your `append` function is faulty**
  It adds the appended element to the second place instead of the last place. Note that you don't need the return at the end either. There is also no point in requiring a double-pointer as input to the `append` method. Also, after assigning `head` to `tmp`, it is futile to check tmp against `NULL` as well, since it won't be `NULL` if `head` isn't `NULL`. Also, I recommend checking the new node against `NULL` as well. If it is `NULL`, this saves you from iterating over the entire collection.
- **The `create_list` function is sub-optimal**
  Fist, the distinction between the first and the other cases are futile. Introducing another pointer (called `current` in my code) will eliminate the need to check whether it is the first or not. Next, you always call the `append` function on the `head`, thus you always need to iterate over the entire collection. This can be also optimized by introducing the `current` variable. (Which, at start, should be assigned the value of `head`.)
- **The `print_list` function is errornous**
  It doesn't print anything if there is only one node. It also redundantly checks the pointers for null. (The beginning of the loop checks it, too.) The return statement at the end of this `void` function is also unnecessary.
- **You should free up memory when you don't use it**
  @Baltasarq wrote a nice `clear` function in his answer, you should use it. :)

### Not serious errors, but you should be aware of them

- You should not use `void*` instead of `char*`
  If you know that the `data` member of the `NODE` structure is going to store characters, why do you use `void*`? It is bad practice! (Unless you have a good reason, of course.)
- Using the `new` word as a variable name makes your code not compliant with C++. Thus, I recommend against it.
- Adopt a better coding style, please - it will make your code so much easier to read
- Inconsistency: if in `print_list` you don't allocate a new variable to go through the collection (like you do with the `tmp` variable in `append`) then it is misguiding to name the parameter as `head`. (I renamed it to `node` in my code.)

### Here is the fixed code

*(Note that there may be small syntax errors because I typed the code into the browser without actually testing it.)*

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node
{
    void *data;
    struct node *next;
} NODE;

NODE *new_node(void *data)
{
    NODE *newNode = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    if (newNode)
    {
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        return newNode;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void append(NODE *head, NODE *node)
{
    if (head && node)
    {
        NODE *tmp = head;
        while (tmp->next)
            tmp = tmp->next; 
        tmp->next = node; /* add as last node */
    }
}

void print_list(NODE *node, void (print_fn) (void*))
{
    while (node)
    {
        if (print_fn)
            print_fn(node->data);
        else
            printf("Word: %s\n", (char *)node->data);

        node = node->next;
    }
}

NODE *create_list()
{
    FILE *dict_file = fopen("trial.txt", "r");

    if (dict_file)
    {
        NODE *head = NULL;
        NODE *current = head;

        char word[20];
        memset(word, '\0', 20);

        while (fgets(word, sizeof(word), dict_file))
        {
            // Creating a variable on the heap
            char *data = calloc(sizeof(word) + 1, sizeof(char));
            // Copying the contents of words to it
            strcpy(data, word);

            append(current, new_node((void*)data));
            if (current->next)
                current = current->next
        }
        fclose(dict_file);
        return head;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ERROR: File not found");
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NODE *head = create_list();

    if (!head)
    {
        printf("ERROR: Either malloc() failed or data not found\n");
    }
    else
    {
        print_list(head, NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Venemo I used void* since tomorrow I might need to have some struct as data for my linked list.

Comment: @movieyoda - Valid point. Does your application work with my code?

Comment: @movieyoda - Edited my answer to include the `print_list` function.

Comment: You should also take into account to clear the list freeing all nodes and data pointers.

Comment: @Baltasarq - The memory allocated to the application automatically gets freed when the application exits.

Comment: @Venemo, don't think so. Maybe I'm missing something big, but a call to malloc() or calloc() should be matched by a call to free() (if you are thinking about the SO freeing the heap, there are chances that there could be a memory leak). Also, program exit code should be EXIT_SUCCESS or EXIT_FAILURE, not TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: @Baltasarq - I don't really know what you mean by "the so", but I know that the operating system has to free **any** memory allocated to an application when the application exits.

Comment: @Venemo: That's not true. There are numerous instances where the OS cannot free memory allocated to a process. This doesn't include malloc, afaik, but does include things like the global COM heap. Assuming that the OS will clean up after you is a bad habit to get into.

Comment: @DeadMG, @Baltasarq - Okay, I get your point. :) I will update my answer as soon as I have the time. Btw, as far as I can see, this example does not use the global COM heap. Keep in mind, this is an example and not a real-world application.

Comment: @Venemo: Great. So you want to set an example of leaking memory? That's perfect.

Comment: @DeadMG - I get your point, but my answer already provides way more info than the question asked for. As I said, I will update it to free memory once I will have the time. :)

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, since *malloc()* and derivatives can answer with a NULL pointer when there is not enough memory. In fact, take into account that you'll also need a *clear()* method that free's all the data, as well as the nodes themselves.

```
void clear(NODE *node)
{
    NODE * temp = NULL;

    while( node != NULL ) {
       temp = node->next;
       free( node->data );
       free( node );

       node = temp;
    }
}
```

Your main() function should return an exit code to the operating system of EXIT_SUCCESS or EXIT_FAILURE, instead of TRUE or FALSE.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NODE *head = create_list();
    int toret = EXIT_SUCCESS;

    if(!head)
    {
        printf("ERROR: Either malloc() failed or data not found\n");
        toret = EXIT_FAILURE;
        clear( head );
    }
    else
    {
        print_list(head, NULL);
        clear( head );
    }

    return toret;
}
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for writing that `clear` function! I added to my answer that he should check yours for it. :)